# Does the following sound realistic as callouts during takeoff?

Tags: takeoff, terminology, pilots

> “Set power.”
> “Power is set.”
> “80 knots.”
> “Check.”
> “Constant power.”
> “V1.”
> “Rotate.”
> “V2.”
> “Positive rate.”
> “Gear up.”

I am unsure about "Constant power." The original text I am translating from has "推力保持" lit. *thrust maintain*, but I couldn't find actual sample dialogue online with that particular callout (I could find everything else), so I was wondering if someone could take a look for me.

Edit: Did some more Googling - is it "Throttle hold"? Or is that not a callout?

Thank you so much!